# Regex working in Athena but not in Spark SQL even after escaping characters

Tags: regex, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, amazon-athena

I'm using Spark SQL to convert [duration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations) to seconds. Here is what I've tried in Athena and works fine.

Athena Code :

```
`SELECT regexp_extract(duration, '^P(?!$)(\d+(?:\.\d+)?Y)?(\d+(?:\.\d+)?M)?(\d+(?:\.\d+)?W)?(\d+(?:\.\d+)?D)?(T(?=\d)(\d+(?:\.\d+)?H)?(\d+(?:\.\d+)?M)?(\d+(?:\.\d+)?S)?)?$') as sec 
FROM table 1 where duration = 'PT0.46S'`
```

### OUTPUT : 0.46S

The same code even after using backslash '' returns null. I have tried using "r" as well before the select clause and it's not working.

What do I need to change in my approach to make it work in Spark SQL

Spark SQL Code :

```
> spark.sql("SELECT regexp_extract(duration,
> '^P(?!$)(\\\\d+(?:\\\\.\\\\d+)?Y)?(\\\\d+(?:\\\\.\\\\d+)?M)?(\\\\d+(?:\\\\.\\\\d+)?W)?(\\\\d+(?:\\\\.\\\\d+)?D)?(T(?=\\\\d)(\\\\d+(?:\\\\.\\\\d+)?H)?(\\\\d+(?:\\\\.\\\\d+)?M)?(\\\\d+(?:\\\\.\\\\d+)?S)?)?$')
> as sec FROM table where duration = 'PT0.46S'").show()
```

### OUTPUT : null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you just need to specify the correct capture group index, which is 8, given your regex definition. Capture group 8 you've defined is `(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?S)` and it contains a trailing literal "S" - this matches "0.46S" in your input. Note, that the default capture group index in Spark SQL `regexp_extract(str, regexp[, idx])` is 1 (see [Spark SQL docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#regexp_extract)), which with your input 'PT0.46S' is empty because there are no matches for what you've defined as the first capture group: `(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?Y)`.

Also, I don't know if it's a formatting issue in your IDE but 4 backslashes is a bit too much for Spark - try just 2. So your Spark SQL would look like:

```
spark.sql(
    """SELECT regexp_extract(
        duration,
        '^P(?!$)(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?Y)?(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?M)?(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?W)?(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?D)?(T(?=\\d)(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?H)?(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?M)?(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?S)?)?$',
        8
    ) as sec FROM table where duration = 'PT0.46S'
    """
).show()
```

Returning:

```
+-----+
|  sec|
+-----+
|0.46S|
+-----+
```

P.S.
On another note, I strongly suggest trying  Regex101 if you still haven't. Best place to troubleshoot regexes, they also have a UI to see what patterns you're actually capturing.

Comment: Thanks! I was missing the capture group index. After adding the index the below expression worked for me : `('^P(?!$)(\\\\d+(?:\\\\.\\\\d+)?Y)?(\\\\d+(?:\\\\.\\\\d+)?M)?(\\\\d+(?:\\\\.\\\\d+)?W)?(\\\\d+(?:\\\\.\\\\d+)?D)?(T(?=\\\\d)(\\\\d+(?:\\\\.\\\\d+)?H)?(\\\\d+(?:\\\\.\\\\d+)?M)?(\\\\d+(?:\\\\.\\\\d+)?S)?)?$', 8)`